# Chrome extension content script not working on chrome webstore page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have simple chrome extension with content script that is supposed to be executed on every site, this works on all sites except this one:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard
```

It works on any other website (google, gmail, internet banking, stackoverflow)

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Chrome extension not working on one site",
"short_name": "cenwoos",
"description": "This chrome extension does not work on chrome webstore site, the content script simply will not be executed.",
"version": "0.1.0",
"minimum_chrome_version": "38",

"permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
]
}
```

content.js:

```
alert('this alert will not be displayed on chrome webstore page');
console.log('This is content script on url:', document.location.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Chrome extensions are not allowed to run on Chrome Store page.
Reasons - Obviously security. A malicious extension can manipulate access to official chromestore page.

[image: Notice no content script injected on chromestore page]